# Why would postfix/smtpd DNS lookup fail?

Tags: debian, docker, dns, postfix

I am preparing a replacement for a 2 years old mail server — Postfix on Debian. The changes are:

- amd64 → arm64
- Debian 10.2 → 11.2
- Postfix 3.4.7 → 3.5.6

The configuration stays the same.

When I try to manually (using `telnet`) deliver an email message to the new server it fails to lookup the sender's hostname:

```
postfix/smtpd[146]: lookup gmail.com type A flags 
postfix/smtpd[146]: dns_query: gmail.com (A): Host not found, try again
postfix/smtpd[146]: lookup gmail.com type AAAA flags 
postfix/smtpd[146]: dns_query: gmail.com (AAAA): Host not found, try again
postfix/smtpd[146]: lookup gmail.com type MX flags 
postfix/smtpd[146]: dns_query: gmail.com (MX): Host not found, try again
```

The old server does it just fine:

```
postfix/smtpd[5554]: lookup gmail.com type A flags 
postfix/smtpd[5554]: dns_query: gmail.com (A): OK
postfix/smtpd[5554]: dns_query: reply len=43 ancount=1 nscount=0
postfix/smtpd[5554]: dns_get_answer: type A for gmail.com
```

`sudo -s -u postfix dig +short mx gmail.com` works fine on both servers.

The output of `postconf | grep dns` is identical on both servers. So is `/etc/resolv.conf`.

What could possibly be wrong with the new one? What else could be debugged to find it out?

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options timeout:2 attempts:5
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search us-west-2.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
```

`postconf | grep dns`:

```
disable_dns_lookups = no
dns_ncache_ttl_fix_enable = no
dnsblog_reply_delay = 0s
dnsblog_service_name = dnsblog
lmtp_dns_reply_filter =
lmtp_dns_resolver_options =
lmtp_dns_support_level =
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
postscreen_dnsbl_action = ignore
postscreen_dnsbl_max_ttl = ${postscreen_dnsbl_ttl?{$postscreen_dnsbl_ttl}:{1}}h
postscreen_dnsbl_min_ttl = 60s
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map =
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 1
postscreen_dnsbl_timeout = 10s
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = 0
smtp_dns_reply_filter =
smtp_dns_resolver_options =
smtp_dns_support_level =
smtp_host_lookup = dns
smtpd_dns_reply_filter =
```

If this is relevant, the "servers" are actually docker containers running `supervisor` as the main command which in turn runs `/usr/sbin/postfix -c /etc/postfix start-fg` as one of the managed processes.

Comment: Thank you. When you say that `dig` works fine, really the question you should be asking is `dig +short mx gmail.com`. Does this return the expected result on both systems?

Comment: @roaima Yup that works on both. I do it as root though. Now thinking maybe should try it as the `postfix` user? How?

Comment: @roaima Also, if that matters, both "servers" are actually docker containers where the main command is `supervisor` which in turn runs postfix. Maybe the new postfix version needs some additional DNS processes or something?

Comment: `sudo -s -u postfix`. The docket bit is relevant; can you add that to your question too please. I'm now thinking firewalls or network routing

Comment: @roaima If there was a way to see how postfix runs its `dns_query` and try the same from command line that would shed some light I guess.

Comment: In your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, I would get rid of the `options` line. I would also change `search us-west-2.compute.internal` to `search .` as a start since that line is going to add `us-west-2.compute.internal` initially to any queries you make. So `gmail.com` becomes `gmail.com.us-west-2.compute.internal` which should then fail before it reverts to plain `gmail.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix runs chrooted by default. It knows nothing about `/etc/resolv.conf`, it looks for `/var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf` instead. Which will not be there unless something creates it there.

To quickly fix the immediate problem, it is sufficient to:

```
cp /etc/resolv.conf /var/spool/postfix/etc/
```

On Debian, that is autimatically done by running `/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh` from `/etc/init.d/postfix` — which is in turn executed when Postfix service is started/stopped etc.

In a docker container none of that will be executed unless done so explicitly. Simply running the command `/usr/sbin/postfix -c /etc/postfix start-fg` does not cut it — it just starts Postfix which sees no `resolv.conf`.

To get it right, Postfix can be run as:

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh - && /usr/sbin/postfix -c /etc/postfix start-fg"
```

Alternatively, Postfix can be configured to run normally i.e. non-chrooted. This is a security consideration — even in a docker container if there is something to hide from malicious SMTP exploits e.g. the mail storage.

Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/661621/why-do-i-have-to-manually-copy-etc-services-and-etc-resolv-conf-into-var-spoo

Comment: It's not clear why it could get deleted but the solution is good enough. If you are using docker then you may prefer not to chroot anything (check master.cfg I think).  Docker containers are already a chroot environment.

Comment: @PhilipCouling "could get deleted"? I'm not sure if it is created in the first place.

Comment: AFAIK it should be copied when you start the service on Debian. At least that's what I remember it doing. Otherwise the default chrooted configuration would be broken from the moment you installed it (seems unlikely)